# Does "for" in these examples fit the meaning of "concerning"?

Tags: prepositions

Consider:

> Deﬁned contribution plans involve very little risk **for** employers.
>
> A combination of negative equity returns and declining interest rates is a nightmare **for** all managers of deﬁned beneﬁt plans.
>
> Sometimes, the extreme market moves are measured in standard deviations, as was the case **for** our exchange rate example.
>
> An analyst could then search to find what multiplier must be applied to the changes observed in the past **for** a particular loss level to be reached.
>
> A bank should enhance its stress-testing approaches **for** its highly leveraged counterparties.
>
> Financial institutions should ensure that their capital will be in good shape not just **for** the specified scenarios, but also **for** other similar or related scenarios.
>
> Unfortunately human beings are not good at estimating a probability **for** the
>   occurrence of a rare event.
>
> -- *Risk Management and Financial Institutions*, 3rd Ed. written by John Hull.

Does "for" in these examples fit the 3rd definition (concerning someone or something) in the [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/for_1)?

And are these "for + nouns" adverbial or attributive?

Please help walk me through them.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make an attempt to rewrite each of your sentences without using for:

> Deﬁned contribution plans involve very little risk **with respect to** employers.
>
> A combination of negative equity returns and declining interest rates is a nightmare **with respect to** all managers of deﬁned beneﬁt plans.
>
> Sometimes, the extreme market moves are measured in standard deviations, as was the case **with the example that concerned** our exchange rate.
>
> An analyst could then search to find what multiplier must be applied to the changes observed in the past **that would cause** a particular loss level to be reached.
>
> A bank should enhance **those** stress-testing approaches **which concern** its highly leveraged counterparties.
>
> Financial institutions should ensure that their capital will be in good shape not just **as they relate to** the specified scenarios, but also for other similar or related scenarios.
>
> Unfortunately human beings are not good at estimating a probability **of the likelihood of** the
> occurrence of a rare event.

Based on this exercise, I would say the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: I think some of your rephrasing are just semantically valid, but not grammatically valid. They could share a similar meaning just because they happen to. A different sentence with the same pattern might not work in your way.

Comment: My intent in going to the trouble of writing all of these was to show grammatically correct sentences (which each of them are) that demonstrate the use of the word *for* to mean *concerning something or someone* as the OALD has it.  I believe that my demonstration is compelling.  One may always argue that a conclusion drawn on a simple preponderance of evidence is invalid because it could be nothing more than coincidence.  However, the more evidence there is, the weaker the argument of coincidence becomes.  (more)

Comment: For example, the more times that water comes through your apartment ceiling when the person upstairs takes a shower, the harder it is to argue that the juxtaposition of these events is unrelated and due to coincidence.  So, if you are unconvinced of the OALD's definition, I encourage you to continue your research and see if you can find evidence of usage that runs contrary to it.  I believe I have shown (and quite effectively, if I may say so) how the sentences you provide support the definition.